# scrollViewDidScroll does not go into the condition

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have setup `scrollView` delegate and implemented the logic into scrollViewDidScroll protocol method as follows, it never goes into the second condition. I wonder what I am missing?

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollOffset == 0)
    {
        // then we are at the top
    }
    else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == 700.0)
    {
       // never calls here 
       [self loadSecondFromURL];
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are checking for `scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight` being exactly 700.0. Try setting a break point and looking at the values.

Comment: I put a break point, it never hits there.

Comment: Put the break point on `if (scrollOffset == 0)` or add a log message to output the value of `scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight`.

Comment: if your scrollView height is 700 it will never go to second condition.

Comment: the simplest way is print NSLog and debug your code

Answer (score 1):

I think scrollOffset is zero so, its entering only first loop. I changed the code like this and it works fine for me

```
if (scrollOffset == 0)
{
    // then we are at the top
}

if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == 700.0)
{
   // never calls here 
   [self loadSecondFromURL];
}
```